# which php-fpm, nginx or related config variable effects whether source file changes are checked by the server?

Tags: php, nginx, php-fpm

i am using nginx with php-fpm (on centos) and a while ago i found a variable in one of the various config files that determines whether the server checks for the existence and/or change status of each of the served php files (as i comprehend what was occurring there).
i read that one setting increases server performance and so i chose that setting.
i found i needed to restart php-fpm service manually for changes that i made to my website's code to be picked up by nginx and served.

i recently upgraded php and this setting is no longer as it was and i am not recalling what the parameter name/token is.. so i am not able to re-activate it.
does anyone know what the variable is?
thanks

Comment: Check the previous version of the config file...you did have it in version control, right? :)

Comment: no version control, no. ;)
the upgrade process asked me to compare or replace the various php config files and i carefully compared them line by line. i continue!

Comment: `yum install etckeeper`. You won't regret it.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably thinking of the "stat" setting in apc.  It's located in /etc/php.d/apc.ini or /etc/php/conf.d/apc.ini depending on your distro.

You want to have `apc.stat=1` to make it check for file modifications, as you said it will result in a significant performance loss, so you should keep it disabled in production.

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.stat for more info.

---

For newer PHP versions using OPcache, the setting you want to enable is validate_timestamps in your opcache.ini.  You'll also then need to set revalidate_freq to how often you want it to check for modifications.  A setting of 0 would make it check every request.

So,

```
opcache.validate_timestamps=1
opcache.revalidate_freq=0
```

Comment: hmm.. possibly.. 
i read that php 5.5 uses opcache and that apc is best disabled now. maybe i need to read more about opcache.

Comment: can you post output of php -m?

Comment: you didn't specify which version of php you were using.. updated my answer with the equivalent setting in opcache

Comment: php -m 
=
    [PHP Modules]
    apc
    apcu
    bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
gmp
hash
iconv
igbinary
imagick
json
ldap
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
memcache
memcached
mhash
mongo
mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_pgsql
pdo_sqlite
pgsql
Phar
posix
readline
recode
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
SPL
SQLite
sqlite3
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tidy
tokenizer
wddx
xdebug
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Xdebug

Comment: php version = 5.5.3
i already downloaded the gist info page from here:
https://gist.github.com/ck-on/4959032/?ocp.php


i notice opcode is not activated there.

and so far i have not seen it say 'enabled' there for opcode, despite me having gone through all the steps in various walkthroughs to activate opcode caching.